# Is there a way to get all managed entities from an EntityManager

Tags: jpa, persistence, entity-relationship

I'm setting up a basic test data util and want to keep track of all the data that the EntityManager handles. Rather than just having a bunch of lists for each entity is there a way to grab everything being managed by the EntityManager in one fell swoop?

So instead of this:

```
EntityManager em;
List<Entity1> a;
List<Entity2> b;
...
List<Entityn> n;

cleanup() {
    for(Entity1 e : a) em.remove(e);
    for(Entity2 f : b) em.remove(f);
    ...
    for(Entityn z : n) em.remove(z);
}
```

I want something like this;

```
EntityManager em;

cleanup() {
    List<Object> allEntities = em.getAllManagedEntities(); //<-this doesnt exist
    for(Object o : allEntities) em.remove(o);
}
```

Not sure if this is possible, but I just would image that the manager knows what it is managing? Or, if you have any ideas of managing a bunch of entities easily.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this might help:

```
for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
    final String className = entity.getName();
    log.debug("Trying select * from: " + className);
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("from " + className + " c");
    q.getResultList().iterator();
    log.debug("ok: " + className);
}
```

Basically **EntityManager::MetaModel** contains the MetaData information regarding the Entities managed.

Comment: For anyone else passing by: The variable name "className" mislead me a bit as it is actually the jpaEntityName. To get the actual class one should use getBindableJavaType. @Faisal, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I am not sure that does what the OP asked for. It seems to print all entities that can be fetched from the database, but not all entities that are *currently* managed by the EntityManager.

Comment: This is just plain wrong! As @MarcusJuniusBrutus is already pointing out, this loads all rows of all known entities from the DB. When the code finishes you can actually get a hand on all loaded entities. But this are not the entities which where managed before executing the code.

Answer (score 3):

What JPA provider are you using?

There is nothing in the JPA API for this.

If using EclipseLink, you can use,

```
em.unwrap(UnitOfWorkImpl.class).getCloneMapping().keySet()
```

Comment: And for Hibernate you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460796/hibernate-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-objects-currently-in-the-session

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove all entities inserted during a test, you can execute the test inside a transaction and then rollback that transaction. See [9.3.5.4 Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx)
as an example of this approach.